# Leibniz Rule for integrating a wave solution with fixed limits.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am thinking about the partial derivative of an integral of a wave solution over a wavelength. I think that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial} {\partial x} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\phi) d\phi
\end{align*}
in which $\phi = kx + mz$ should be zero since the result of the integral is independent of $x$. However, I am not sure about how to compute
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial} {\partial x} \int_0^{l} A(x) \sin(\phi) d\phi
\end{align*}
in which $A(x)$ is the amplitude that depends on $x$, and $l$ is some constant. My intuition tells me that the answer should be
\begin{align*}
A'(x) \int_0^{l}  \sin(\phi) d\phi
\end{align*}
but I am not very sure. I guess I have to apply Leibniz Rule but that would gives
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{l} \frac{\partial} {\partial x} (A(x) \sin(\phi)) d\phi = \int_0^{l}  (A'(x) \sin(\phi) + A(x) \cos(\phi) \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}) d\phi
\end{align*}
However, I don't know how to continue and I am confused by the dependence of $\phi$ on $x$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May be your confusion comes from that you mess $x$ and $\phi$. If you write exactly very first integral, what it will be?

Comment: I know it is zero... but what’s wrong with my last integral?

Comment: When you put expression for $\phi$, in first integral what will be variable for integration?

Comment: I am not sure... but if we substitute $\phi = kx + mz$ then there are two independent variables?

Comment: Sorry, but it is decisive, because if variables are $\phi, x$, then substitution $\phi = kx + mz$ gives $$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\phi) d\phi = \int_{\frac{-mz}{k}}^{\frac{2\pi-mz}{k}}k \sin (kx+mz)dx$$